Why is this algorithm O(n*n) - Manacher algorithm implementation?
So I was recently doing leetcode problem number 5 - longest palindromic substring, which outputs the longest palindromic substring out of a string. I have studied Manacher's algorithm but I didn't exactly remember it so I tried to recreate it from what I know.
What I wrote is this:
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        s = ''.join(['#' + c for c in s]) + '#'
        n = len(s)
        dp = [0] * n
        maxLength, l, r = 0, 0, 0
        for i in range(1, n):
            oglength = dp[i]
            while (i - dp[i] - 1 >= 0 and i + dp[i] + 1 < n and s[i - dp[i] - 1] == s[i + dp[i] + 1]):
                dp[i] += 1
            
            if dp[i] > maxLength:
                maxLength = dp[i]
                l = i - dp[i]
                r = i + dp[i]
            
            for curr in range(i + oglength + 1, i + dp[i] + 1):
                mi = 2 * i - curr
                dp[curr] = mi - (i - dp[i]) if mi - dp[mi] < (i - dp[i]) else dp[mi]
                curr += 1

        return ''.join([s[i] for i in range(l, r + 1) if s[i] != '#'])

which leetcode analized to be with a time complexity of O(n*n) and gave a result in 600 ms. The correct implementation is:
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        s = '@' + ''.join(['#' + c for c in s]) + '#' + '$'
        n = len(s)
        dp = [0] * n
        c, r = 0, 0
        lengthmax, centermax = 0, 0
        for i in range(1, n - 1):
            mirror = 2 * c - i
            if i < r:
                dp[i] = min(r - i, dp[mirror])
            while s[i - (dp[i] + 1)] == s[i + (dp[i] + 1)]:
                dp[i] += 1
            
            if dp[i] > lengthmax:
                lengthmax = dp[i]
                centermax = i
            
            if i + dp[i] > r:
                c = i
                r = i + dp[i]

        return ''.join([s[i] for i in range(centermax - lengthmax, centermax + lengthmax) if s[i] != '#'])

My question is why is the first one so much slower than the second one. In my implementation we go trough all new addition to the found palindrome and then the for loop takes care of updating their dp values in relation to that original center. Because it takes care of new addition's one index woudn't be inspected more than once in these for loops so to my understanding the complexity will be O(3*n)??

Note that ['#' + c for c in s] already implies at least O(n²) as time complexity. Secondly, time complexity does not imply anything about running times for actual values of n.

Woah, leetcode shows analized time complexity now? Where? I don't see it.

Since you have a for loop inside another for loop, it is O(n^2).
The outer for loop runs n times. Each iteration of the for loop calls another for loop, going from i + oglength + 1, i + dp[i] + 1. This inner for loop will be run less than n times. Therefore, your function needs to do n*(n-k) calculations, where k changes for each iteration of the loop.
n*(n-k) expands out to n^2 - nk. Sińce n^2 is of a higher degree than nk, we ditch the nk term and are left with just n^2. Therefore, the time complexity is O(n^2).
Now let's have a look at Leetcode's solution.
Similarly, they have an outer for loop, which runs n times.
However, their inner while loop can run at most one time; therefore, its complexity is O(1). Here is why:
while s[i - (dp[i] + 1)] == s[i + (dp[i] + 1)]
is equivalent to
while s[i - dp[i] - 1] == s[i + dp[i] + 1] (simple algebra)
Since they are indexing the same array, we can further simplify this down to
while i - dp[i] - 1 == i + dp[i] + 1
Now, when 1 is added to dp[i] inside the loop, i - dp[i] - 1 decreases by 1 and i + dp[i] + 1 increases by 1. Therefore, after just one iteration of the loop, the termination condition will be reached, making its time complexity O(1).

Since we have a few O(1) calculation inside an O(n) loop, the final time complexity is 1*n = O(n).
O(n^2) is a lot slower than O(n) - just put it into desmos, and the huge difference will show itself once n gets big.
Hope this makes sense.

BTW O(3*n) is just O(n)

Your simplification to get rid of the string indexing doesn't make any sense. The whole point of the algorithm is that the string is expected to have duplicate characters (you're looking for a palindrome).
